# Проверка правописания Windows — "Требовать строгое соответствие ё"

Tags: windows

Знает кто-нибудь, как программно:

a) Узнать текущее состояние тумблера?

b) Включить/выключить тумблер?

[image: "Требовать строгое соответствие ё"]

Comment: Что конкретно вас интересует — способ вмешаться в интерфейсы чужих программ или только управление этим самым строгим соответствием?

Comment: В чужое вмешиваться точно недосуг, мне бы для начала со своим дерьмом разобраться (а что, кстати, какой тут вектор атаки может быть в принципе?): подключаю встроенную проверку орфографии к своему софту, но данная опция пока больше мешает, чем помогает — не все пользователи понимают, как данная опция работает (с активированным тумблером как ошибочные подчёркиваются даже правильные на их взгляд слова), и хотелось бы если не дать им возможность менять её состояние, то хотя бы узнавать текущий статус и отображать его для них где-нибудь в UI на видном месте.

Comment: Просмотр действий через Sysinternals Process Monitor говорит, что этот тумблер дёргает ключ в реестре `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Spelling\Options\ru-RU:StrictYoh`

Comment: Спасибо, это действительно оно. Продублируйте отдельным сообщением, пожалуйста. Я отмечу его как правильный ответ.